# Are rvs $X$ and $2X$ independent?

Tags: probability, independence

Suppose you have a random variable $X$. Intuitively one thinks that the random variables $X$ and $2X$ will not be independent.

But I think it is not so if $X$ follows a point mass distribution, that is $\exists x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(X = x_0) = 1$

**Claim**: Let $X$ be a discrete RV that follows a point mass ($x_0$) distribution, $X$ and $2X$ are independent.

*Proof*: Need to show that $P(X=a, 2X=b) = P(X=a)P(2X=b)$, for all values $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

Case 1: $a=x_0, b=2x_0$ then $P(X=a, 2X=b) = P(X=x_0, 2X=2x_0) = P(X=x_0) = 1$ and $P(X=a)P(2X=b) = P(X=x_0)P(2X=2x_0) = 1$

Case 2: $a=x_0, b \neq 2x_0$ then $P(X=a, 2X = b) = P(X=x_0, 2X = b (\neq 2x_0)) = 0$ and $P(X=a)P(2X=b) = P(X=x_0)P(2X = b) = 0$

Similarly, $P(X=a, 2X=b) = P(X=a)P(2X=b) = 0$ for the other two cases also.

Are there any other corner cases where such counter-intuitive thing happens?

Comment: It is not so counter intuitive because the variable is not really random (we say it is “constant”). The converse is true: if $X$ is independent of $2X$ then $X$ is constant (almost surely).

Comment: @nejimban I would still say it is coutner-intuitive or not is debatable (or perhaps just that I don't have a very good intuition). For the other claim you made, could you give me a hint to proceed? I want to start with: suppose $X$ is not a constant... if I assumed X is discrete then it is easy. But if I assumed X is continuous then I am not sure.

Comment: Please also observe that: For any trivial event $E$, i.e. $P(E) = 0$ or $P(E) = 1$, then $P(E \cap E) = P(E) = P(E) \times P(E)$ which means that $E$ is independent to itself. The degenerate / constant random variable also has a trivial sigma algebra and thus have the similar property

Comment: @BGM Thank you. I got so mixed up in formulas that it didn't occur to me that independence of rvs can be thought of in terms of sigma-algebras generated by them. In particular, that if two rvs generate a trivial sigma-algebra then they are always independent. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Any two constant rvs are always independent**. This can be seen easily following the comments above from @BGM.

Formally, let $X$ and $Y$ be two rvs (defined on the same probability space). Say $X \equiv x_0$ and $Y \equiv y_0$

Denote by $E_x$ the event $X \leq x$. Then $P(E_x) = 0$ if $x < x_0$ and $P(E_x) = 1$ otherwise. Similarly we denote by $E'_y$ the corresponding events for $Y$.

Then notice that $P(E_x \cap E'_y) = P(E_x)P(E'_y)$. Can be easily proved as follows:

Case 1: $x < x_0$. $P(E_x) = 0 \implies P(E_x \cap E'_y) = 0$

Case 2: $y < y_0$. $P(E'_y) = 0 \implies P(E_x \cap E'_y) = 0$

Case 3: $x \geq x_0$ and $y \geq y_0$. Only need to show that intersection of probability $1$ sets is also of probability $1$, which is left as an exercise for the reader :)